# After running a sql command the date format changed. However i am unable to convert back to the actual date formate

Tags: r

My actual data had the correct date format which is shown below:

```
$ INVOICE_DATE            : Date, format: "2020-05-08" "2020-05-11" ...
 $ DUE_DATE                : Date, format: "2020-06-07" "2020-06-10" ...
 $ POSTING_DATE            : Date, format: "2020-05-11" "2020-05-12" ...
```

However after i run a sql code in r the date format changed to numeric format and now i am not able to convert to the actual date format.

```
Open_prediction_final<-sqldf("select Open_prediction.*,Open_data.SUPPLIER as SUPPLIER_ID from Open_prediction  join
                             Open_data on Open_prediction.INVOICE_ID=Open_data.INVOICE_ID")

str(Open_prediction_final)
$ INVOICE_DATE            : num  18390 18393 18393 18397 18397 ...
 $ DUE_DATE                : num  18420 18423 18423 18427 18427 ...
 $ POSTING_DATE            : num  18393 18394 18394 18400 18401 ...
```

Comment: No idea. I can generate a frame with dates and join it on itself and still get dates back. Perhaps you could add the output from `dput(head(Open_prediction))` and `dput(head(Open_data))`, ensuring that there is enough commonality in the samples to actually join something (My code that works fine: `dat <- data.frame(dates = Sys.Date() + sample(10,3)); sqldf::sqldf("select d1.dates from dat d1 left join dat d2 on d1.dates=d2.dates ");`, overly complex but still returns dates.

Comment: See FAQ #3 on the sqldf github home page. https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the SQL query returns numbers in first place since we don't have the data but probably, you can convert `Open_prediction_final` back to dates.

```
Open_prediction_final[] <- lapply(Open_prediction_final, as.Date, origin = '1970-01-01')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just found that in my Open_data the date format is as below:DUE_DATE         : POSIXct[1:4400], format: "2020-06-11" "2020-06-10" ...

Comment: I believe this is the reason why after joining the date format was converted to number. Is there any way i can resolve this issue

Comment: @Numita Try `Open_data$DUE_DATE <- as.Date(Open_data$DUE_DATE)` and then run again.